# Android app crashes on intent

Tags: android, android-intent

My app is working fine, I have a main menu, but on the main menu when I hit "play" , my app crashing, here is the logcat when i'm pressing the button:

```
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): Process: com.example.theball, PID: 4072
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.theball/com.example.theball.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:142)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3242)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowEx.generateLayout(PhoneWindowEx.java:20)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3305)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:334)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:328)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1993)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.example.theball.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     ... 11 more
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     ... 26 more
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2150)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3565)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:101)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:97)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:52)
07-07 08:35:34.505: E/AndroidRuntime(4072):     ... 29 more
```

Here is my MainActivity:

```
      package com.example.theball;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
        private SensorManager sensorManager;
        private Sensor accelerometer;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private long lastUpdate;
        AnimatedView animatedView = null;
        ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        public static int x;
        public static int y;
        public static final int width = 50;
        public static final int height = 50;
        public boolean firstDraw = true;
        private int screen_width; 
        private int screen_height; 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            accelerometer = sensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
            setContentView(animatedView);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                x -= (int) event.values[0];
                y += (int) event.values[1];
                if(x <= 0 || x >= screen_width || y <= 0 || y >= screen_height) { 
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        }
        public class AnimatedView extends ImageView { 
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            Point size = new Point(); 
            static final int width = 50; 
            static final int height = 50; 
            @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
            public AnimatedView(Context context) { 
            super(context); 
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
            display.getSize(size); 
            screen_width = size.x; 
            screen_height = size.y; 
            mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape()); 
            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23); 
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height); 
            }

            @Override 
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height); // left top right bottom 
            if(firstDraw) { 
            x = screen_width / 2; 
            y = screen_height / 2; 
            firstDraw = false; 
            } 
            mDrawable.draw(canvas); 
            invalidate(); 
            } 
            }
}
```

Here is my android manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.theball"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.theball.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.theball.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.theball.help"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

TY :) if you need something more just ask :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because of `setContentView(animatedView);` in the `MainActivity.java`.

It is causing `OutOfMemoryError`

So ***if you are using an emulator*** then **increase your RAM size** or otherwise try to **reduce the size of the images etc** you are using.

Comment: Ok, I am not using an emulator.. LG G2, now I am trying to reduce the size of the images.

Comment: It worked, I switched my 4K background to some 225X225 background and it fixed that :P

Comment: cheeres :) happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

From the logcat it is clear the error is **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError** which can happen when you try to handle large image bitmaps.

[This](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) is the official doucumentation.

Comment: So emm.. What can I do?

Comment: Try to sample the bitmap image to reduce the size